# What is the most efficient way of checking XML for a set of attributes?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have a folder `m_d` of very many identically structured xml files that I want to sort. Two examples are below. If any word element of any xml file contains attributes `"N", "E", "D", "P", "L"` I want to copy the file to another folder. Only 'xml file 1' would thus be copied.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

xml file 1

```
<root>
  <l id="130">
    <word id="0.5" N="I">amet</word>
    <word id="1.0" E="s"/>
    <word id="2.0" f_0="j">consectetur</word>
    <word id="2.1" t_0="a" D="B">adipiscing</word>
    <word id="2.2" P="I">elit</word>
    <word id="2.4" L="B">do</word>
    </l>
</root>
```

xml file 2

```
<root>
  <l id="131">
    <word id="2.0" f_0="j">consectetur</word>
    <word id="2.1" t_0="a">adipiscing</word>
    </l>
</root>
```

code

```
import os
from lxml import etree
import shutil

m_d = "/m"
m = os.listdir(m_d)
a_d = "/a"

for xml_file in m:
    if not xml_file.endswith(".xml"):
        continue
    
    input_dir = os.path.join(m_d, xml_file)
    input_file = open(input_dir,"r",encoding="utf-8")
    output_dir = os.path.join(a_d, xml_file)
    parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
    tree = etree.parse(input_file, parser)
    root = tree.getroot()
    targets = ["N", "E", "D", "P", "L"]

    for word in root.findall('.//word'):
        for target in targets:
            if target in word.attrib:
                shutil.copy2(input_dir, output_dir)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: A minor tip but if you want to get a specific file extension in a directory [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) is a wonderful tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), your task seems easy by doing an [`intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) :

```py
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

attrs = ["N", "E", "D", "P", "L"]

for xml_file in os.listdir(m_d):
    if xml_file.endswith(".xml"):
        input_path = os.path.join(m_d, xml_file)
        shared_attrs = pd.read_xml(input_path, xpath="./*/*").columns.intersection(attrs)

        if shared_attrs.size == 5:
            output_file = os.path.join(a_d, xml_file)
            shutil.copy(src=input_path, dst=output_file)
```

Output :

```
..
 ┣━━ m
 ┃   ┣━━ file1.xml
 ┃   ┗━━ file2.xml
 ┗━━ a
     ┗━━ file1.xml # <-- copied/created
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks. Is there a way of amending this so that instead of copying files that contain all values in `attrs`, files that contain at least one value in `attrs` are copied?

Comment: Yes, use `shared_attrs.size >= 1` instead of `shared_attrs.size == 5`.

Answer (score 2):

Counting elements with at least 1 of such attributes

```
>>> targets = ["N", "E", "D", "P", "L"]
>>> doc = etree.parse('tmp.xml')
>>> hasAttrs = doc.xpath(f'count(//word[@{" or @".join(targets)}]) > 1')
>>> hasAttrs
True
```

Effective xpath: `count(//word[@E or @N or @D or @P or @L]) > 1`