# XPath to match all elements in an array

Tags: xpath, xquery

I am trying to write a condition that applies if an element contains all the attributes in a predefined list but I can not seem to get the XPath correct.

Example data:

```
let $element := <country type="" class="" ref="" ana=""/>
return 
    if($element/@*[local-name() = ('type', 'class', 'ref', 'ana')]) then 
        'All attributes are present'
    else 'You can add attributes'
```

The first condition returns true if any of the attributes are present, I'm not sure what the correct XPath is to make sure they are all present.

Thanks,
Winona

Comment: Just use [`count(//element[@type and @class and @ref and @ana]) > 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75986719/2834978)

Comment: I need to match the attribute names against a list.

Comment: I don't know which language are you using but you can check the linked answer where the xpath predicate is dynamically built against a list. All in all, your code shows a hardcoded inline list, just rewrite as shown in previous comment,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a literal list I would just use `and`:

```
if ($element[@type and @class and @ref and @ana]) ...
```

If the list is not known statically, you can use `every`

```
if (every $name in $list satisfies exists($element/@*[local-name()=$name])) ...
```

or more concisely (but less readably)

```
if ($list[not(. = $element/@*/local-name())]) ...
```

Another option is:

```
if (count($element/@*[local-name()=$list]) = count($list)) ...
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! I used the second option and it works exactly as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try using a [quantified expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-quantified-expressions)...

```
let $element := <country type="" value="" ref="" ana=""/>
return 
if (every $attr in ('ana','ref','type','value') satisfies $element[@*[local-name()=$attr]]) then 
    'All attributes are present'
else 
    'You can add attributes'
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do, using [`fn:matches()` `Regex`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-matches):

```
let $element := <country type="" class="" ref="" ana=""/>
return
    if($element/@*[matches(local-name(), 'type=.*\sclass=.*\sref=.*\sana=')]) then
        'All attributes are present'
    else 'You can add attributes'
```